# How can I fix arguments detection problem

Tags: android, kotlin

[I gave some arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcZ57.png)

[.ı defined some arguments above the picture but I cant sent any parameter here.Android studio does not detect this.How can I fix this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diyrE.png)

Error given below:
Too many arguments for public open fun actionListFragmentToRecipeFragment(): ListFragmentDirections.ActionListFragmentToRecipeFragment defined in com.example.foodrecipeapp.ListFragmentDirections

Answer (score 0):

If your arguments have default values you can't pass them to invocation directly instead use like this

```
val action = ...
action.info = "my info"
action.id = 1
```